# How to drag a solid color rectangle in a Win32 app without white flickering and without interfering with other on screen objects?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, drag, gdi

I've been messing around with a little toy Win32 app to try and get the hang of basic drawing and processing mouse and keyboard messages. Basically, the goal is to click around the client area to place rectangles, alt click them to cycle through 4 colors, right click them to reassign a color directly with one of the f keys, or right click and hold to reposition with drag and drop, with the currently selected rectangle having a dotted outline instead of solid.

Dragging correctly is proving to be difficult. While dragging, the selected rectangle being dragged flashes white / flickers, and also temporarily erases the pen drawn borders of the other rectangles. Overcoming these two issues is what I need help with.

A c++ vector is being used to collect and process dynamically allocated CRect objects, in case it matters.

```cpp
    //relevant code from WndProc

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            ClipCursor(&rcClip);
            if (prcSelected)
            {
                prcSelected->deselect();
                prcSelected = nullptr;
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            }
            int x{ LOWORD(lParam) }, y{ HIWORD(lParam) };
            for (auto rc : vRect)
            {
                if (rc->IsClicked(x, y))
                {
                    rc->select();
                    prcSelected = rc;
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            ClipCursor(&rcOldClip);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            if (wParam & MK_RBUTTON && prcSelected)
            {
                CRect rcPrev{ *prcSelected };
                CRect crIsect{};
                int x{ LOWORD(lParam) }, y{ HIWORD(lParam) };
                int xShift{ x - prcSelected->r.left }, yShift{ y - prcSelected->r.top };
                prcSelected->shift(xShift, yShift);     
                rcPrev.SetFill(CR_WHITE);
                rcPrev.SetOutline(CR_WHITE);
                rcPrev.draw();

                for (auto rc : vRect)
                    if (IntersectRect(&crIsect.r, &(rc->r), &(rcPrev.r)))
                    {
                        crIsect.SetFill(rc->GetFill());
                        crIsect.SetOutline(rc->GetFill());
                        crIsect.draw();
                    }

                prcSelected->draw();
            }
        }
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            for (auto rc : vRect)
                rc->draw(hdc);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
            break;


    //Rectangle drawing code

    void CRect::draw()
    {
        HDC hdc{ GetDC(hWnd) };
        HPEN hpenDot;
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, crBrush);
        if (!fSelected)
        {
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN)); // Can be set to any color. No need to release.
            SetDCPenColor(hdc, crPen);
            Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
        }
        else
        {
            hpenDot = CreatePen(PS_DOT, 1, crPen);
            SelectObject(hdc, hpenDot);
            Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
            DeleteObject(hpenDot);
        }
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }

    void CRect::draw(HDC& hdc)
    {
        HPEN hpenDot;
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, crBrush);
        if (!fSelected)
        {
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN)); 
            SetDCPenColor(hdc, crPen);
            Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
        }
        else
        {
            hpenDot = CreatePen(PS_DOT, 1, crPen);
            SelectObject(hdc, hpenDot);
            Rectangle(hdc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
            DeleteObject(hpenDot);
        }
    }


    void CRect::shift(int x, int y)
    {
        r.left   += x;
        r.top    += y;
        r.right  += x;
        r.bottom += y;
    }

    bool CRect::IsClicked(int x, int y)
    {
        POINT pt{ x, y };
        return (bool)PtInRect(&r, pt);

    }
```

Comment: Rather than drawing directly to the screen, render the whole window to an off-screen bitmap and then blit it to the screen in a single call.

Comment: A standard way of dragging rectangles that has been around since forever is to draw using XOR.  To erase the rectangle, you simply draw it with XOR again and then draw the new one.  You could also read up on [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd).  If none of these helps, consider double-buffering: i.e. do all your drawing in an offscreen bitmap and blit that when updating the window.

Comment: A classic way to drag/move/drop pictures with smooth animation  is with ImageList APIs (_ImageList_BeginDrag_ and so on) [Test](https://i.ibb.co/yfJx4Mq/Image-List-Drag.gif)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you should do painting only in WM_PAINT handler.

Instead of painting directly on screen surface in WM_MOUSEMOVE handler you should do the following:

1. In `WM_MOUSEMOVE` just call `InvalidateRect(,prcSelected)`  to invalidate area occupied by your drag rectangle.
2. In your `WM_PAINT` handler

   ```
   case WM_PAINT:
   {
       PAINTSTRUCT ps;
       HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

       // clear surface
       FillRect(hdc, ps.rcPaint, COLORREF(0xFFFFFF));

       for (auto rc : vRect)
           rc->draw(hdc);

       if(prcSelected)
         DrawDragRectangle(...); // drawing code from your WM_MOUSEMOVE

       EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
   }
   ```

This way you will do drawing in WM_PAINT only and in correct order.

You may still have flickering even in this case.  If so enable double buffering on your window by adding [WS_EX_COMPOSITED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) flag to it.